# GitHub actions deploys wrong version of Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, json.net, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have a GitHub action doing .net solution build, test and deploy to Azure:

```
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - project-test-api

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  # Stop wasting time caching packages
  DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: true
  # Disable sending usage data to Microsoft
  DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: true
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: AutoModality/action-clean@v1
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Manually restore
        working-directory: SolutionDir
        run: dotnet restore --force

      - name: Build with dotnet
        working-directory: SolutionDir
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
        
      - name: Test
        working-directory: SolutionDir
        run: dotnet test --no-restore --no-build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        working-directory: SolutionDir
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'quickplanner-test-api'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_SECRET }}
          package: .
```

Recently I added a test project to the solution. From what I can see one of the packages used in the test project uses Newtonsoft.Json v9.0 when the rest of the solution uses v13.0. The solution can be built locally, tested and everything is ok. The GitHub action also finishes successfully building the solution, runs tests and deploys it to Azure. The problem occurs on Azure - somewhere along the way GitHub action uses an older version of Newtonsoft.Json. All projects expect newer ones, so the whole website breaks because of this. I'm not sure how to fix this - I've tried adding manually correct version of Newtonsoft.Json to the test project, to all projects, clearing caches in GitHub actions but without luck. What works is just removing test project from the solution, but obviously I want tests to be working. Does anyone has idea why this breaks and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by adding this code to my Tests project csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm not entirely sure what was the root cause behind this problem